# Complex Makefile with Python and Shared Libraries

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have next to no experience in Makefiles, and I'm trying to learn - and I understand most of it.  But, I have a directory structure like this:

```
/src/
    /mysql/
        mp_mysql.h
        mp_mysql.c
    /sqlite/
        mp_sqlite.h
        mp_sqlite.c
/lib/
    mysql.so
    sqlite.so
```

And I'm trying to write a makefile that compiles the files in `/src/mysql` into `/lib/mysql.so` and do the same for sqlite.  I could probably get it if someone helped me along!  Thanks!

P.S. The project is a Python project, and I'm writing a special adapter in C for MySQL.  All of the resources I've found online I can't get to work and/or work to make one big executable.

Comment: Do you care where the object files (`mp_mysql.o`, `mp_sqlite.o`) go?

Answer (score 0):

First, write a Makefile for each directory and define a DIR_BUILD variable, which can be overridden when calling `make`.

Then, write a project Makefile which runs each of the child Makefiles.

For example,

```
DIR_BUILD = '.'

mysql.so: mp_mysql.c mp_mysql.h
    gcc $< -o $(DIR_BUILD)/$@
```

and, for the parent Makefile:

```
SUBDIRS = `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

all:
    for d in $(SUBDIRS);                               \
    do                                                 \
      $(MAKE) --directory=$$d DIR_BUILD=../lib;       \
    done
```

No guarentees, let me know how it goes!